# Only even index positioned bars are displaying x axis value in plotly bar chart

Tags: python, plotly

```
trace = go.Bar(x=list(month_values.keys()), y=list(month_values.values()))
    # Defining layout with title, x-axis, and y-axis labels
    layout = go.Layout(
        title='Months',
        xaxis=dict(title='Month'),
        yaxis=dict(title='Count'),
        title_x = 0.5,
        title_y = 0.87
    )

    # Creating figure object that includes both trace and layout
    fig = go.Figure(data=[trace], layout=layout)

    # Displaying the chart
    iplot(fig)
```

I used the above code snippet to create a Bar chart using the Plotly Library , but x axis values are visible only for the even indexed bars.

[image]

Help me to get the x-axis values to be visible for all the bars.

Comment: If you don't want to treat the x-axis as a time series, just set the x-axis as a category. `fig.update_xaxes(type='category')`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to set the tick mode to linear, which means Plotly will display one tick per **category**. You can also adjust the tick angle and font size to make the labels more visible. For example, you can add the following lines to your code:

```
fig.update_xaxes(tickmode="linear", tickangle=-45, tickfont_size=10)
```